# Multi Vendor / Multi Seller store in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento-enterprise, theme, multistore

Can the new Magento 2 be able to implement these features easily ?? especially the multiple shops for each shopkeeper ? or a lot of customization will have to be done ?

Comment: as Till now M2 does not have a multi vendor Feature , You may check https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Marketplace.html for Magento2 multi vendor option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inital Magento 2.0 release will probably not be suited better for multiple vendors than Magento 1 because there are no big changes planned for the first release. It's too early to tell whether there will be improvements later on.

Magento 2 should be improved in terms of scalability but it would probably take a big refinement like the [uDropship extension](https://secure.unirgy.com/products/udropship/) from Unirgy for M1 to make M2 really capable of being a market place where many hundreds or thousands of shop owners can sell their products in one place.

In Magento 1, the Enterprise Edition allows you to create separate admins for each website which could kind of help the separation of stores.

Disclaimer: I'm not related to Unirgy and never have used the extension but I heard that many shops are using it.

Comment: i think i wont wait for magento 2 ..will go ahead with magento 1 and once 2 is stable probably within within one and a half years from today will deploy magento2 and my extension would probably be upgraded thereafter

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. If one of our replies answers your question please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) because it helps us getting the answer rate up and this site out of its beta status.

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 will basically have the same features as Magento 1. With a few extra's.

The functionalities you are discribing are pretty broad and it's hard to give a good answer on that. But I don't expect Magento 2 to support your whole case.

Check out [this blogpost](http://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2.html) about Magento 2 to learn more about it's features

Comment: So i think im just going to deploy magento 1.8 rather than wait upto next year and still the system is unsure if it would have a stable release + plus addons would still need to keep up with the changes !! what do u think ?

Comment: @CosmiBli Magento is already at 1.9.1. I advice you to use that version. But sounds like a good plan!

Comment: You may check here as well https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-multi-vendor-marketplace.html

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 is entirely different from its previous version Its coding style is different and also have some new feature.It is not a diffcult functionality to add in Magento2.Once you understand the Magento2 coding styles you will be able to add the functionality. Magento2 is now moving towards stability and their are extension already available which help in bringing multivendor functionality in Magento2 store.

You may find this article useful - [MultiVendor Functionality in Magento 2.0](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-marketplace-addons-module-for-Magento-2-02-already-or-is-it-too-soon)

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2 is very good! You can used some extensions bellow, They are compatible with Magento 2.

- https://www.magebay.com/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace-extension
- https://secure.unirgy.com//products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace

Comment: You may check webkul marketplace addon as well https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Marketplace.html